# MPMovieplayerVideoController playing after changing view

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmoviewcontroller

I am playing video using MPMoviePlayerController in my view play and pause and stop working correctly but when I change the view (also in diddisapear remove the player) video playing after some second (2 or 3 sec.) , how it is possible ??

Comment: post code u have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just create and stop using NSNotitificationCenter now its working.. :)